# Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, aurelia

I have been trying desperately for a month to figure out a way to get JavaScript  intellisense to work for Aurelia in Visual Studio 2017. I know there is no definitions in npm @types. I tried to copy over the index.d.ts file from the local node_modules folders to a folder in the Salsa Cache at c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Typescript\2.5\@types that is named the same as the Aurelia module, along with the package.json. It didn't work. I tried adding a jsconfig.json. Also didn't work. Is there anyone with Aurelia intellisense working in VS 2017????????

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is applicable  to your installation, but there is a known issue (https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1344) with type definitions when Aurelia is installed via jspm. The solution for now, unfortunately, is to also install Aurelia as a dev dependency via npm.

```
npm install --save-dev aurelia-framework aurelia-bootstrapper aurelia-pal-browser aurelia-polyfills
```

This takes up more space, but should resolve the issue until it's fixed properly.